# Uncaught TypeError: $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

what I'm trying to do is to move from page to anthor page by this code :

```
if (($("#UserIDTXT").val() == "3164") && ($("#UserPassTXT").val()) == "12345678")
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#HomePage", { reloadPage:true });
```

any mistakes ?

Comment: i dont think that the mistake is on the blocks, i'll copy some code.

Comment: function checkDetails()

{

    
    if (($("#UserIDTXT").val() == "3164") && ($("#UserPassTXT").val()) == "12345678")

        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#HomePage", { reloadPage:true });

}

Comment: i called it here, 
<input type="button" onclick="checkDetails()" value="התחבר">

Comment: are you sure it has to be `pageContainer.pageContainer`? or just `$.mobile.pageContainer("change", "#HomePage", { reloadPage:true }); } `

Comment: maybe.. i'll check, i just copied it from anthor topic answer

Comment: no, Uncaught TypeError: $.mobile.pageContainer is not a function

Comment: ok, This is how pageContainer works then https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/ , are you sure $.mobile is not undefined ?

Comment: i just copied what you wrote without the last "}" and that's error again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting an error that `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer` is not a function, then either you are not including the jQuery Mobile library correctly, you are using an old version, or you are executing your `pageContainer` code before the document has fully loaded.

Additionally, your usage of the `change` action is slightly incorrect.

Change this:

`if (($("#UserIDTXT").val() == "3164") && ($("#UserPassTXT").val()) == "12345678")
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#HomePage", { reloadPage:true });`

To this:

```
if (($("#UserIDTXT").val() == "3164") && ($("#UserPassTXT").val()) == "12345678") {
    var jqHomePage = $("#HomePage");
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", jqHomePage, {});
}
```

I removed the `reloadPage` option in your first example because it is deprecated as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 and should not be used.

Comment: Second argument can be an object or a string.

Comment: still not working, i wrote as you said, Uncaught TypeError: $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer is not a function
    at checkDetails (CityFixJS.js:21)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:29)

Comment: i think that this function (checkDetails) should be in anthor function maybe like init ??

Comment: you are the only who's helped me, i posted this question 3 time, Thumbs up bro!